# Deadlock on Update Postgres from Trigger function

Tags: postgresql, deadlock, database-trigger

I'm running postgres 9.4. I have an events table where each row represents an event with a name for a specified user.

```
event id (primary key)
event name
user_id (foreign key in users table)
```

I have a trigger function which checks the name of the event, and if it matches certain names, adds some data to columns in the user table for the matching user_id.

However, I am getting deadlock errors - I think it's due to the way I've specified my function.  Can anyone advise how to structure the function to avoid errors?

```
BEGIN

IF NEW.name = 'labvar1' THEN
    UPDATE users SET labvar1=new.name WHERE new.user_id = users.user_id;
    UPDATE users SET labvar1_properties=new.properties WHERE new.user_id = users.user_id;

ELSIF NEW.name = 'labvar2' THEN
    UPDATE users SET labvar2=new.name WHERE new.user_id = users.user_id;
    UPDATE users SET labvar2_properties=new.properties WHERE new.user_id = users.user_id;

ELSIF NEW.name = 'labvar3' THEN
    UPDATE users SET labvar3=new.name WHERE new.user_id = users.user_id;
    UPDATE users SET labvar3_properties=new.properties WHERE new.user_id = users.user_id;

ELSIF NEW.name = 'labvar4' THEN
    UPDATE users SET labvar4=new.name WHERE new.user_id = users.user_id;
    UPDATE users SET labvar4_properties=new.properties WHERE new.user_id = users.user_id;

ELSIF NEW.name = 'labvar5' THEN
    UPDATE users SET labvar5=new.name WHERE new.user_id = users.user_id;
    UPDATE users SET labvar5_properties=new.properties WHERE new.user_id = users.user_id;

ELSE
RETURN null;
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deadlock means that you are having two transactions locking each other out.

Read about [deadlocks](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/explicit-locking.html) and why is it happening in the manual.

---

In order to update two columns in a table you don't need to run two separate statements. You can combine this in one statement like that:

```
UPDATE users 
  SET labvar1 = NEW.name, 
      labvar1_properties = NEW.properties 
WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks @consider Me.  I managed to resolve my deadlock by splitting out into separate if /end if blocks for each event.